# Python heapq: Split and merge into a ordered heapq

Tags: python, heap, priority-queue

I am wanting to split two heapqs (used as a priority queues), and then add them together and have the resulting heapq ordered in relation to both of the previous heapqs.

Is this possible in python?

My current code:

```
population = []
for i in range(0, 6):
    heappush(population, i)
new_population = []
for i in range(4, 9):
    heappush(new_population, i)

split_index = len(population) // 2
temp_population = population[:split_index]
population = new_population[:split_index] + temp_population
print(population)
print(heappop(population))
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
4
```

Wanted output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
0
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to reheapify the new list: `population = heapq.heapify(new_population[:split_index] + temp_population)`.

Comment: Taking half of the underlying list like this seems like an arbitrary action to perform. You aren't guaranteed to get the top/bottom half of the elements of the original.

Comment: Thank you! I am using it for a genetic algorithm. Thus I take the two better halves of populations and add them together!

Comment: Like I said in my most recent comment, the first half of the elements in the list are *not* the top n/2 elements in the priority queue.

Comment: @chepner I see. Is there a way I am able to half them, and then add the halves together so that they contain the best values from both populations?

Comment: You can use `heapq.nlargest` and `heapq.nsmallest` instead of slicing to get your two halves, then use `heapq.heapify` to rebuild the queue from the two halves.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nlargest` instead of slicing, then reheapify the combined lists.

```
from heapq import nlargest, heapify
n = len(population) // 2
population = heapify(nlargest(population, n) +
                     nlargest(new_population, n))
print(heappop(population))
```

---

You may want to benchmark, though, if sorting the two original lists, then merging the results, is faster. Python's `sort` routine is fast for nearly sorted lists, and this may impose a lot less overhead than the `heapq` functions. The last `heapify` step may not be necessary if you don't actually need a priority queue (since you are sorting them anyway).

```
from itertools import islice
from heapq import merge, heapify
n = len(population)  # == len(new_population), presumably
population = heapify(islice(merge(sorted(population), sorted(new_population)), n))
```